# LEFT JOIN with ON regarding first table

Tags: sql

Since LEFT JOIN needs every entry on the first table what if you try to limit the first table with ON?  Can someone explain what is going on in this query

```
SELECT *
FROM College LEFT JOIN Apply 
ON College.cNAME = 'Stanford'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of a `left join` is that it takes all rows from the first table *regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to `true`, `false`, or `null`*.

So, what happens?  The columns from the first table are all present.  However, the columns from the second table will be `NULL`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a5c901153a33e748ee367dd3ae33f1f) is a db<>fiddle illustrating what happens.

Comment: So is this kinda of like a situation where you would never run this query but SQL just gave some default behavior.

Comment: @bakalolo . . . SQL does what SQL does.  It is processing this the same way as any other join.  There is no special or default behavior.

Comment: I think my understanding of SQL is lacking so I just say that it's a behavior instead of trying to explain it through logic